# How to add multiple return type hints in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, return-type

I'm using this function in which I'm either returning JsonResponse or Http Response, based on which format the user requested. How to return type hint both of the returns?

```
public function findAll(array $data)
{
    $countryRepository = new CountryRepository();

    $countries = $countryRepository->findAll();

    if ($data['data_format'] === DataFormat::JSON) {
        $countriesMapper = new CountryResource($countries);
        return new JsonResponse($countriesMapper->collection($countries), HttpStatusCode::HTTP_OK);
    } elseif ($data['data_format'] === DataFormat::XML) {
        $xmlResponse = $this->responseFactory->view('XML.country.list', compact('countries'))->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        return $xmlResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK php does not have type hinting on returns. You can put it in a doc block using phpdoc

Comment: You won't be able to return two different types, but I believe as of PHP 7.2, you can return an object type. In this case you can return an interface that both JsonResponse and HttpResponse implements. Generally speaking, it is not recommended to return different types since on the caller side, you would have to determine what the type is before you can operate on it. Whereas if you return an interface, the caller can invoke a set of methods without having to determine if it exists.

Comment: I would make separate functions: `findAllJSON(array $data) : JsonResponse` and `findAllXML(array $data) : XmlResponse`

Answer (score 0):

If both response types inherit from the same parent class I *think* you can use that as type-hint. I remember reading that something about this was planned for php 7.4.

```php
class JsonResponse extends Response { ... }
class XmlResponse extends Response { ... }

public function findAll(...) : Response { ... }
```

Or you could make it a void return and give the responsability to other methods

```php
public function findall(...) : void {
    switch($data['data_format']) {
        case DataFormat::JSON:
            $this->returnJson(...);
            break;
        case DataFormat::XML:
            $this->returnXml(...);
            break;
        default:
            # error
            break;
    }
}
protected function returnXml(...) : XmlResponse {}
protected function returnJson(...) : JsonResponse {}
```

Comment: You can type-hint parent classes and interfaces since type-hinting is possible.

Comment: Thanks. I know it works for interfaces but I wasn't sure about it working with parent classes.

Comment: Technically, it's pretty much the same principle. I think what you stumbled over is covariant return types and contravariant parameters. It basically says that a child class can have different method return types than the parent class, namely more specific ones (i.e. parent has return type `Vehicle` and child class `Car` or another child class `Bycicle` for the same method). With parameters it would be the opposite thing, you'd be able to support more generic types in the child class than in the parent class (e.g. `object` in child vs. `Vehicle` in parent class).

Comment: ...Yeah, pretty much.